# RSpec 3.6 and Rails 5.0.1 - ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (given 0, expected 1)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, testing, rspec

I'm trying to write a mailer test using RSpec. However, it is failing and I cannot figure out why. My failure notification is the following:

```
Failures:

  1) UserMailer welcome_email sends an email upon new user registration
     Failure/Error:
       def welcome_email(id)
         @user = User.find(id)
         mail(to: @user.email, subject: 'Welcome on board!')
       end

     ArgumentError:
       wrong number of arguments (given 0, expected 1)
     # ./app/mailers/user_mailer.rb:4:in `welcome_email'
     # ./spec/mailers/user_mailer_spec.rb:10:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

The relevant code in the file I'm testing is the following:

```
class UserMailer < ApplicationMailer
  default from: 'noreply@example.com'

  def welcome_email(id)
    @user = User.find(id)
    mail(to: @user.email, subject: 'Welcome on board!')
  end
end
```

And this is my spec:

```
require "rails_helper"


RSpec.describe UserMailer, :type => :mailer do
  describe "welcome_email" do
    let(:mail) { UserMailer.welcome_email }

    it 'sends an email upon new user registration' do
      expect(mail.subject).to eq('Welcome on board!')
    end   
  end
end
```

I have tried all suggestions for this error I could find elsewhere to no avail. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your method `welcome_email` takes one parameter but you are not passing nothing here

```
let(:mail) { UserMailer.welcome_email }
```

Comment: When I try the following:

`let(:mail) { UserMailer.welcome_email(1) }`,

I get this error:

`ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound:
       Couldn't find User with 'id'=1`.

I'm assuming this is because I'm working in a local environment with nothing in the DB. How can I put some sort of wildcard argument that will test regardless of what is in the DB?

Comment: I believe part of the answer involves the use of [factory_bot](https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_bot).

Comment: Yes, I had to use factory_bot and create a User, including adding the ID manually.

Comment: I'm sorry, I was sleeping :D have you solved your problem?

Comment: I have. Thank you!